# Python OpenCV - how to find ONLY rotation and translation needed to align two images given two sets of points? (no Affine, no warping)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have two sets of matching points, eg.

```
# first set of points
[[696.0, 971.3333333333334], [1103.3333333333333, 934.6666666666666], ...]
# second set of points
[[475.0, 458.6666666666667], [1531.3333333333333, 524.0], ...]
```

from two images. Right now I'm using this piece of code to align images:

```
points_source = np.array(source_coordinates)
points_destination = np.array(destination_coordinates)

h, status = cv2.findHomography(points_destination, points_source, cv2.RANSAC)
aligned_image = cv2.warpPerspective(destination_image, h, (source_image.shape[1], source_image.shape[0]))
```

It works well most of the time, but sometimes it warps image and it aligns bad. I found `estimateRigidTransform` function, that'd be the best for me, because it's possible to only translate and rotate the image, but it's deprecated and when I try to use it, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "align.py", line 139, in <module>
    align(image, image2, source_coordinates, destination_coordinates)
  File "align.py", line 111, in align
    m = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(points_destination, points_source, fullAffine=False)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'estimateRigidTransform'
```

I couldn't find any other solution than `estimateRigidTransform`. Is there any other function that'd work for me? Maybe I can use `warpPerspective` to only change rotation and translation? I don't want to use `getAffineTransform` function because it can accept only three points and I want to use much more points. My OpenCV version is `4.0.1-1`

Comment: You can't use cv2.estimateRigidTransform()? It works for me on OpenCV version 4.0.0-pre.

Comment: @StephenMeschke no, I can't, it throws an error on 4.0.1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function I needed is: `cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain OpenCV, I would recommend to link your project with another library that has the algorithms you are looking (for and much more). Probably the best solution would be [Insight Toolkit library (ITK)](https://itk.org) or [Visual Toolkit (VTK)](https://vtk.org). The former is much complex and also much harder to learn, but the latter is actually very simple. They both use CMake and there is no problem in compiling/linking etc.

ITK is especially designed for image processing. It includes so called *Landmark based registration*, which is exactly what you need. Complete working example is [available](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Registration/LandmarkBasedTransformInitializer). Unfortunately, the library seems very complex at the beginning.

On the other hand, VTK also implements the same algorithm, but it can be used very simply ([From the example](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/LandmarkTransform)):

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLandmarkTransform> landmarkTransform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLandmarkTransform>::New();
landmarkTransform->SetSourceLandmarks(sourcePoints);
landmarkTransform->SetTargetLandmarks(targetPoints);
landmarkTransform->SetModeToRigidBody();
landmarkTransform->Update();
std::cout << landmarkTransform->GetMatrix() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for the libraries, they might be helpful for me in the future! But right now I'd rather stick with OpenCV